# Generate Excel file with chart with data from mysql database using PHP

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, excel-charts

I want to generate an excel file with chart based on the data from MySQL database using PHP with PHPExcel Library.
I searched a lot..but could not find a solution
Values are exported to the excel file.but the chart doesnt show up.

```
require_once 'includes/PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

//Data Series Labels
$dsl=array(
                new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Data!$C$1', NULL, 1),
                new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Data!$D$1', NULL, 1),

            );
//X Axis Value Label
$xal=array(
                new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Data!$C$2:$C$91', NULL, 90),
            );
//Data Series Values
$dsv=array(
                new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Data!$C$2:$C$91', NULL, 90),
                new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Data!$D$2:$D$91', NULL, 90),
            );
//set up Data Series
$ds=new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
                    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_LINECHART,
                    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD,
                    range(0, count($dsv)-1),
                    $dsl,
                    $xal,
                    $dsv
                    );
//create the Plot Area and Legend
$pa=new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea(NULL, array($ds));
$legend=new PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, NULL, false);
//create chart
$chart= new PHPExcel_Chart(
                    'chart1',
                    $title,
                    $legend,
                    $pa,
                    true,
                    0,
                    NULL, 
                    NULL
                    );

$chart->setTopLeftPosition('K1');
$chart->setBottomRightPosition('M5');
$ews->addChart($chart);
//title of chart
$title=new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Any literal string');

$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($ea, 'Excel5');

$writer->setIncludeCharts(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a solution from https://www.sitepoint.com/generate-excel-files-charts-phpexcel/ .

Comment: link only answers are discouraged

Comment: I think affaz will get the proper solution from this link. Because putting the whole code of that link here it not feasible.

Comment: pls see my edited post..i was able to export data to excel using the link you provided but the chart didnt appear.I have attached the code above.Thanks